# Creating SOAP client using Quarkus cannot import @CXFClient

Tags: soap, quarkus

Working with SOAP Web service in Quarkus using [quarkiverse/quarkus-cxf](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-cxf)
Try to implement a client using this [example](https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-cxf/dev/client.html)

```
import com.example.FruitWebService;                   // SEI
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import io.quarkiverse.cxf.annotation.CXFClient;

@Application  // or any other CDI scope
public class MySoapClient {

    @Inject @CXFClient
    FruitWebService clientService;

    public int getCount() {
        return this.clientService.count();
    }
}
```

Cannot import `@CXFClient` Im using the following `quarkus-cxf` extension

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkiverse.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-cxf</artifactId>
      <version>0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need at least Version `0.8` of the plugin. So update your `pom.xml` to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkiverse.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-cxf</artifactId>
  <version>0.8</version>
</dependency>
```